# database schema for http transactions

Tags: sql, http, normalization, database-schema

I have a script that makes a http call to a webservice, captures the response and parses it.

For every transaction, I would like to save the following pieces of data in a relational DB.

1. HTTP request time
2. HTTP request headers
3. HTTP response time
4. HTTP response code
5. HTTP response headers
6. HTTP response content

I am having a tough time visualizing a schema for this.
My initial thoughts were to create 2 tables.

```
Table 'Transactions': 
1. transaction id (not null, not unique)
2. timestamp (not null)
3. type (response or request) (not null)
3. headers (null)
4. content (null)
5. response code (null)
```

'transaction id' will be some sort of checksum derived from combining the timestamp with the header text.

The reason why i compute this transaction id is to have a unique id that can distinguish 2 transactions, but at the same time used to link a request with a response.

What will this table be used for?
The script will run every 5 minutes, and log all this into the DB. Plus, every time it runs, the script will check the last time a successful transaction was made. Also, at the end of the day, the script generates a summary of all the transactions made that day and emails it.

Any ideas of how i can improve on this design? What kinda normalization and/or optimization techniques i should apply to this schema? Should i split this up into 2 or more tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a NoSQL approach to this, and it has worked. Used MongDB. The flexibility it offers with document structure and not having to have a fixed number of attributes really helped.
Probably not the best solution to the problem, but i was able to optimize the performance using compound indexes.